# MySQL Resource limits

Tags: mysql, resources, limits

whenever i set a Resource limits for particular user/database/host does it spread through the hour? it'll delay queries or does it won't allow you to query would throw some sort of an error or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html says:

> As the server runs, it counts the number of times each account uses resources. If an account reaches its limit on number of connections within the last hour, further connections for the account are rejected until that hour is up. Similarly, if the account reaches its limit on the number of queries or updates, further queries or updates are rejected until the hour is up. In all such cases, an appropriate error message is issued.